# How can users reconnect to chat app after they disconnected (socket js)

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm creating a chat app with sockets where you first come to a landing page to enter your nickname, and then join the chat.

In the chatpage amongst the form and the message-area, I have a disconnect button that takes you back to the landing page. The idea is that you should be able to enter a nickname (same or new) and join the chat again (without seeing previous history).

I manage to send them to the landing page but for some reason they can't reconnect again.

Is there something I'm missing to make that work?

Listen on disconnect on server file

```
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id]);
    delete users[socket.id];
    console.log('bye bye');
  });
```

chat.js emits disconnect and sends back to landing page

```
const feedbackBox = message => {
  showFeedback.innerText = message;
  showFeedback.classList.add('feedback-I-disconnect');
  showFeedback.classList.remove('hide');
  container.appendChild(showFeedback);
};

disconnectButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('disconnect-button')) {
    socket.disconnect();
    messageContainer.classList.add('hide');
    messageForm.classList.add('hide');
    disconnectButton.classList.add('hide');
    appendForm();
    feedbackBox('You disconnected from the chat');
  }
});
```

name.js is the landing page

```
const getName = () => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = nameInput.value;
    socket.emit('new-user', name);
    nameInput.value = '';
    socket.off('name-taken');
    socket.on('name-taken', () => {
      feedbackBox('Nickname already taken');
    });
    socket.off('user-accepted');
    socket.on('user-accepted', () => {
      title.classList.add('hide');
      nameContainer.classList.add('hide');
      addMessageForm();
    });
  });
};

const appendForm = () => {
  nameInput.classList.add('name_input');
  form.appendChild(nameInput);
  submitName.classList.add('submit_name');
  form.appendChild(submitName);
  nameContainer.appendChild(form);
  nameContainer.classList.add('name_container');
  nameContainer.classList.remove('hide');
  title.classList.remove('hide');
  title.classList.add('name_title');
  container.appendChild(title);
  container.appendChild(nameContainer);
  getName();
};
```

Comment: You can call `socket.connect` again from the client, right?

Comment: I see where you call `socket.disconnect()` but not the `socket.connect()`. It seems like it's only called once in a global context perhaps when first loading the page. You need to call it again when the user wishes to reconnect.

Comment: You are both right, I call socket.connect()  inside chat.js after calling the feedbackBox function and it works.
When you reconnect though you can see all the previous messages. Is there a way to clear that history somehow?